# Use Share feature from device gallery to send an image to Ionic app ,similar to share to whatsapp

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have created an ionic app , i don't know how i would share an image to my app from gallery . it would be similar to cordova social share except that cordova social share works in-app. How would i add my app to the list of apps in the share actionsheet.is there any cordova plugin to do this?

[image: Just like here]

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in ionic forum [Here is the link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/list-my-app-on-share-pane-in-ios/26015)